I need to limit my PR validation build pipeline runs, like only 2 PRs can be run whenever 3rd PR is coming it should be in queue
script which im trying
script second part
We do have a build pipeline to validate our PR, whenever a new PR is created this build validation pipeline will start running, here when multiple PRs are running, for a same build pipeline multiple runs are happening right so getting some issues here, to rectify this, we would like to set some restrictions, like only 2 PRs can be run whenever 3rd PR is coming it should be in queue, the pipeline should be in queue actually. how to acheive this?
please let me know if there is any other way to get this done. We are actually trying with custom powershell script, able to get the pipeline runs count, with that count need to set some limitation like if run count is more than 2 put the 3rd run in queue or cancel it anything is fine. At a time, only 2 runs should happen.
Above in screenshot is my script which im trying however no luck.pls help.

Please edit your question and paste the code as text, not images.

Upload your pipeline configuration Yaml file

How is the question related to Bitbucket Pipelines? Please [edit] it and remove that tag

You can set the agent capabilities for two agents and use demands in the pool to make sure the pipeline only run on two agents.
Detailed steps:

Choose Organization settings > Agent pools, select the agent pool you are using for the build pipeline.
Select Agents and choose the desired two agents.

Choose the Capabilities tab, then Add a new capability.

In the build pipeline, use the pool demands  in your yaml:

# for Microsoft-hosted agent 
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest  # or windows-2022
  demands: buildvalidate # exists check for the capability

or
# for self-hosted agent 
pool:
  name: self-hosted pool name
  demands: buildvalidate # exists check for the capability


This way, we can make sure the build pipeline only runs on the two agents with the capability set and whenever 3rd PR is coming, the new build should be in queue.

thanks for this,but is it possible to achieve through any powershell function, like disabling the pipeline trigger if the count run is more than 2. but below is not working.
function Update-PipelineStatus {
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/definitions/$definitionId?api-version=6.0"
$body = @{
"queue" = @{
"status" = "paused"
}
} | ConvertTo-Json
try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body $body

Hi @VinothiniRajasekar, do you mean running a power shell script in this build validation pipeline to determine the current build validation pipeline's position in the queue? In this case, the build validation pipeline will not be in the queue state, because it will be in running state to run the PowerShell task. By the way, please edit your question to share your current pipeline configuration YAML file (paste the code as text, not images).

Hi @VinothiniRajasekar, can you please share your current pipeline configuration YAML file and your power shell script (paste the code as text, not images)?
